# Hendrix tone using a Marshall DSL and Fuzz Face

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, tone, distortion

I'm playing a strat through a Jim Dunlop Fuzz Face (Band of Gypsys edition) into a Marshall DSL5C combo. I'm looking for a starting point for getting a Hendrix-y tone. Can anyone recommend some settings, or advise where to start? Playing the fuzz face into the clean channel doesn't give much sustain, yet fuzz face doesn't have too much impact using the Ultra Gain channel on the DSL.

Comment: A very unscientific comment... but I have a number of Strats, one of which sounds like Hendrix the second you plug it into anything, another that won't do it no matter how much work you put in.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Out of interest, is there anything obvious that might explain this? Different types of pickups, perhaps?

Comment: tbh, between my 2 extreme samples, there is almost nothing in common.. Real 1964 Strat, all original, vs mid 00's Squier. 1st weighs nothing, sounds gorgeous even unplugged, sings like a bird, 2nd weighs a ton, is almost silent unplugged with a sustain you could measure in milliseconds. I have always described it as sounding like 'plasticine'. Both "sound like Strats", as opposed to anything else, but there are really few similarities. You can guess which one sounds like Hendrix ;) In the middle I do have an 85 JP Squier, which feels like the the 00's Squier, but sounds closer to the 60's orig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out all the positions on the pickup selector of that strat. Turn up your amp loud. Stand close to it. You're never going to sound quite like Hendrix, so just make sure that the amp is set such as to produce a balanced sound with various distortion levels available through the dynamics of your playing.

If you were to stack the fuzz face with the distortion channel, set the gain fairly low on both, unless you want it really out of control. Turning up the volume on the fuzz face also helps to saturate the preamp and recreate the sound of an amp melting down.

Comment: Some good suggestions - but on the other hand, front pickup & amp *just* below noticeable distortion when played gently ought to be able to sound like 'Wind Cries Mary'. Hendrix didn't only make one sound ;)

Answer (score 2):

try old marshall distortion pedals, wah-wah like Hendrix used or hire an engineer tomake set of effects for you as Hendrix did. However I am sure that his music sound good if performed well on modern intstruments. Jimmy was a left handed player and it is not easy to copy what he was doing with his guitar, and there is no need to copy anyone exactly, I guess.https://www.groundguitar.com/jimi-hendrix-gear/

Comment: The Fuzz Face is *already* 'true to style', as to some extent is the Marshall - though idk that particular model.